# Sequential definition of continuity implies delta-epsilon definition

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity, epsilon-delta

Let $I$ be an interval, $c \in I$, and $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Consider the following definitions:

(1) For every sequence $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ contained in I such that $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to c, the sequence $\left(f\left(x_{n}\right)\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $f(c)$

(2) $f$ is continuous at $c$ (in the delta-epsilon sense)

I am trying to show that $(1)\implies (2)$

Construct an $\{x_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_{n}\in B_{1/n}(c)$, for each $n$. Clearly, $\{x_{n}\}\rightarrow c$, and so $f(x_{n})\rightarrow c$. Thus, there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N \implies$ $|f(x_n)-f(c)|<\epsilon$. So, set $\delta :=\frac{1}{N+1}$. Then, $|x-c|<\delta$ $\implies$ $x \in B_{\frac{1}{N+1}}(c)\subset B_{\frac{1}{N}}(c)$, so $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon.$

Comment: What is true for $ x_n$ is not necessarily true for $ x$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I realised that upon posting. I am now trying to fix the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Proof by contradiction. We shall prove prove that:
$$
\text{Not}\,(2) \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \text{Not}\,(1).
$$
If not (2), then there exists an $\varepsilon>0$, such that, for all $\delta>0$, there exists a $y_\delta\in I$, with
$$
|y_\delta-c|<\delta \quad\text{and}\quad 
|f(y_\delta)-f(c)|\ge\varepsilon.
$$
In particular, for $\delta=1/n$, define $x_n=y_{1/n}$.

Clealy, $|x_n-c|<1/n$, while $|f(x_n)-f(c)|\ge \varepsilon$, which contradicts (1).